# Insert Many to Many Scenario in EF 4.0 with POCO Classes

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, poco

I have a database schema like follows:

**User** 1 ---- * **UserRole** *----1 **Role**

I have a POCO User and Role classes as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{

    public virtual Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have a business component classes and a data access classes to to handle business logic and the data access.

I wanted to add Roles to a selected user and and the code is like follows:

In Business Component:

```
    public void AssignRoles(User user, string[] roleIds)
    {
        user.Roles.Clear();
        foreach (string roleId in roleIds)
        {
            Role role = new RolesDataAccess().SelectRoleById(int.Parse(roleId));
            if (role != null)
            {
                user.Roles.Add(role);
            }
        }
        this.SaveUser(user);
    }

    public User SaveUser(User user)
    {   
        if (user.Id == 0)
        {
            return dataAccess.Create(user);
        }
        else
        {
            return dataAccess.Update(user);
        }
    }
```

In Data Access:

```
    public User Update(User user)
    {
        EntityKey key = null;
        object original = null;

        using (DocsFlowContext ctx = new DocsFlowContext())
        {
            key = ctx.CreateEntityKey(User.EntitySetName, user);
            if (ctx.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out original))
            {
                ctx.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, user);
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        return user;
    }
```

This code runs without any errors but it doesn't insert any data to my UserRole table. Any one have an idea about this?

Comment: You only add roles if they exist in the database. Can you check that the roles indeed do exist and are added to the `user.Roles` list (just take a look at the `user` object before `SaveChanges` is called).

Comment: I was debuging this and I found that in the update method. ctx.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, user); this code line apply all the changes that have done to the main properties but the Roles list. User.Roles list doesn't get updated. That is the reason it doesn't insert any records to the db. Any ideas on this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class UserRole
    { 
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
    public virtual Role Role {get;set;} 
    }
public class User
{
...
public virtual List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set;}
}

public class Role
{
...
public virtual List<UserRole> RoleUsers { get; set;}
}
```

or

```
public class User
{
...
public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set;}
public virtual Role Role { get; set;}
}

public class Role
{
public virtual List<User> Users { get; set;}
public virtual User User { get; set;}
}
```

first solutions it is look like better,  you should add 
DbSet UserRoles 
to your DbContext

It has been tested EF CTP5 Poco.

Good luck